# PPM - Project Portfolio Management

Tags: project-management, projects, portfolio

What is your company solution for PPM (managing projects, demands, timesheets, etc)? And what is your experience with it?

I'm trying to know about the tool prespective and not your company's particular business process.

Regards for you all!

Comment: [Basecamp](http://www.basecamphq.com/) has been very good for us in the past.

Comment: We have used Project Insight in the past but recently switched to OpenAir: it has a cleaner interface, it's easier to enter timesheets and apparently it also plays nicely with the company's financial system.

Comment: I use Fogbugz for the development and tracking, and xWiki with embedded Balsamiq Mockups to manage all of the documents.

Comment: ProjectForge http://labs.micromata.de/display/pf/Home has project portfolio and human resource management for our steering and JIRA integration for the production, it works well.

Comment: You could also have a look at https://www.omnirocket.com, which has a beautiful overview of your projects (But it doesn't have time sheets)

Answer (score 3):

Roadmap http://www.ppmroadmap.com/ takes the same, lightweight approach as Basecamp and applies it to PPM.  In fact, Roadmap supports real-time integration with Basecamp.  It's reasonably priced and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

In our company ms project standard is used for managing projects, demands, timesheets, etc.
I've used microsoft project gantt chart for project scheduling and tracking, it serves the purpose very well. You can download ms project trial version from microsoft website. You can get more details on ms project at [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/project/en/us/project-professional-2007.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

We use Microsoft Great Plains, and hate it! We also use Siebel Service for defect tracking... and hate it!

A while back we implemented [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/), an open source bug tracking tool for a small project that needed customers to access it (all our corporate apps are internal-access only). Mantis has been so successful we have 3 teams using it and resisting moving to using Siebel.

We also use [dotProject](http://www.dotproject.net/) for project management - its good, but I'm not sure its quite as good as more expensive Project tools.

So, my experience has been that the open source, web based tools are very good (eg [OrangeHRM](http://www.orangehrm.com/), [WebERP](http://weberp.org/), [vTiger](http://www.vtiger.com/)), very useable, (and free), and they do a perfectly good-enough job. The commerical apps can sometimes be complete pants.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio teams, Microsoft's Team Foundation Server is getting much better...2010 provides much more syncing and task hierarchical mgmt then 2008 and 2005 before, but still not a fully healthy PPM solution out of the box...if you have the skills, create an entire process template for your org and really get the power out of TFS. Kudos to msft for the 2010 version and the much improved MS Project 2010 product...I'm in the middle of evaluating this myself.

@task is awesome even in its standard edition suite - expensive, but allows total tracking, mgmt, dashboard, timesheet, doc mgmt, etc, etc, etc right out of the box on a SAAS model.

Basecamp has become the trendy adaptation to the PPM problem. I've used it some with clients, but would love to trial it for myself soon.

Answer (score 0):

In our organization we use Microsoft Project 2010 for [project portfolio management](http://www.microsoft.com/project/en/us/project-portfolio-management.aspx). It is used to gain visibility & control across all projects & teams, helps enhance decision-making, improves alignment with business strategy, helps maximize resource utilization and managing projects by enhancing project execution.  Definitely recommend it.